# RxJs How to complete inner observable

Tags: rxjs

I have function like this:

```
this.eventTaskWorking$ = completeStage
  .pipe(
    map(result => {
      switch (result) {
        case Statuses.LAST_TASK: {
          console.info('returning finish event observable');
          throw { err: 0 };
        }
        default: {
          return EMPTY;
        }
      }
    }),
    catchError(() => completeEvent)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

When i throw an exception, "completeEvent" is completed, but if i try to use switchMap, mergeMap etc...it's not working:

```
this.eventTaskWorking$ = completeStage
  .pipe(
    map(result => {
      switch (result) {
        case Statuses.LAST_TASK: {
          return completeEvent;
        }
        default: {
          return EMPTY;
        }
      }
    }),
    switchMap(t => t),        
  )
  .subscribe();
```

What's wrong?

UPD:

```
const completeEvent = this.FinishEvent(eventRef, uid);

private FinishEvent(eventRef: Observable<IEvent>, taskUid: string): Observable<any> {
return eventRef.pipe(
  switchMap(t => this.UpdateTaskStatus(taskUid, 3)));
}
```

Comment: And "it's not working" means what?

Comment: @cartant completeEvent is a function, that returned observable value, but body of pipe function of this observable is not executed

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems FinishEvent didn't return observable, my fault